# Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed - Naming range and referring to it in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, range, autofilter

Within a single macro, I am trying to select a range, name it, and then refer to that range when AutoFiltering data. Here's my code:

```
'Select and name range
Set bDataDump = ActiveWorkbook
Set DataDump = bDataDump.Sheets(1)    
DataDump.Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Set myrange = Selection

'AutoFilter that range for everything but PDC1 and delete visible rows
    'Code fails on next line
DataDump.Range("myrange").AutoFilter field:=11, Criteria1:="<>""PDC1"""
ActiveCell.Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
DataDump.ShowAllData
```

I get the "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed" when I run the macro, and the debugger highlights the first line of the second block of code as the culprit. I have not been able to find any examples on the web of filtering data like this, so I would appreciate any insight as to what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: lol@pnuts: You make me look like a devil :) :@SMPerron [INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: @pnuts: Oh you have already mentioned the link. Oops...

Comment: @pnuts and Sid: Thanks for the article!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

myrange is a Range and not a String.  Therefore replace:

```
DataDump.Range("myrange").AutoFilter field:=11, Criteria1:="<>""PDC1"""
```

with

```
myrange.AutoFilter field:=11, Criteria1:="<>""PDC1"""
```

Comment: + 1  for explaining the issue :)

Comment: Makes perfect sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
DataDump.Range("myrange").AutoFilter field:=11, Criteria1:="<>""PDC1"""
```

should be

```
myrange.AutoFilter field:=11, Criteria1:="<>""PDC1"""
```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, I present to you my updated code. It includes the replacement of all `.Select` statements.

```
Set bDataDump = ActiveWorkbook
Set DataDump = bDataDump.Sheets(1)
Set myrange = DataDump.Range("A1")
Set myrange = Range(myrange, myrange.End(xlToRight))
Set myrange = Range(myrange, myrange.End(xlDown))
'
myrange.AutoFilter field:=12, Criteria1:="<>PDC1"
Set dltrng = DataDump.Range("A2")
Set dltrng = rnage(dltrng, dltrng.End(xlDown))
dltrng.EntireRow.Delete
DataDump.ShowAllData
```

I find it very strange that the filter part of the recorded macro required doubled quotes

`ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1: ... Criteria1:="<>""PDC1"""`

but required single quotes when starting with a named range (see line 7 above).