# Excel VBA - Filter specific data in Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba

I tried using the code that appeared to have helped the poster at

[Excel VBA - Privot table filter multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42505991/excel-vba-privot-table-filter-multiple-criteria)

But I keep on getting the following error: Unable to get the PIvtoFields property of the PIvotTable Class.

```
Sub FilterPivotItems()

    Dim PT          As PivotTable
    Dim PTItm       As PivotItem
    Dim FiterArr()  As Variant

    ' use an array to select the items in the pivot filter you want to keep visible
    FiterArr = Array("MC. Santa Clara", "MC. Plaza Américas", "MC. El Frutal")

    ' set the Pivot Table
    Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4")

    ' loop through all Pivot Items in "Value" Pivot field
    For Each PTItm In PT.PivotFields("Value").PivotItems
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(PTItm.Caption, FiterArr, 0)) Then ' check if current item is not in the filter array
            PTItm.Visible = True
        Else
            PTItm.Visible = False
        End If
    Next PTItm

End Sub
```

What can I do?

Comment: Add some data and I'll try it here. I need PivotTable4 data.

Answer (score 0):

After reading about the properties of the class, I finally got to what I wanted.

```html
Sub filterpivot()


Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim first As String
Dim second As String
Dim third As String
Dim fourth As String

first = Range("a26").Value
second = Range("a27").Value
third = Range("a28").Value
fourth = Range("a29").Value

Set pt = Worksheets("Lowest Scores").PivotTables("PivotTable4")

    With pt.PivotFields("Nombre conjunto")
        For Each pi In pt.PivotFields("Nombre conjunto").PivotItems
        
        
            If pi.Name = first Or pi.Name = second Or pi.Name = third Or pi.Name = fourth Then
                pi.Visible = True
            Else
                pi.Visible = False
            End If
        Next pi
    End With


End Sub
```

This bases the applied filter on specific cell values. My apologies if anyone was working on this already, I was on a crunch at work and needed the answer.