# Filter out a value in a column whether or not the value is present

Tags: excel, filter, vba

I have the following code:

```
myRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>A", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>B", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria3:="<>C"
```

it works if A, B, and C are in the column. However, I receive an error if for example A, and B are only present but not C. I need to make it work in the premise that A, B, or C may or may not be present in the column. Hope someone can help.

EDIT: Apparently the error came from adding Criteria 3
I'm stuck on how I can filter out more than 2 Criteria

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you're unable to filter out more than 2 criteria's which is what you're running into.

I found the answer to a similar question I had here ([filter out multiple criteria using excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575754/filter-out-multiple-criteria-using-excel-vba))

Rather than restating their answer, see if that thread is helpful.