# Apply boolean autofilter criteria to different language

Tags: excel, vba, boolean, multilingual, autofilter

I have a table which I filter based on a Boolean value.

Whenever the value is `TRUE`, I want it to show.

I use an autofilter and the following working VBA code:

```
lCol = tbl.ListColumns("xFilter").Index
With tbl
    If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=lCol, Criteria1:="TRUE"
End With
```

I am working on an English instance of Excel. When I try this on an instance in Dutch I have to manually set the Criteria to `WAAR` (Dutch equivalent of `TRUE`).

I can add [multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575754/filter-out-multiple-criteria-using-excel-vba) and state:

`Criteria1:="WAAR", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="TRUE"`

However, if I would then go to Germany and Spain I would need to write:

`Criteria1:="WAAR", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="TRUE", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria3:="WAHR", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria4:="VERDADERO"`

**Is there a way to have `Criteria1:="TRUE"` work in any language?**

Comment: Use `Criteria1:=TRUE` instead of `Criteria1:="TRUE"`?  (AFAIK, VBA uses English for its constants, methods, properties, etc, no matter what language version is being used.  But if you are having to cast a `String` to a `Boolean` within Excel, it will use the language applicable to that version of Excel.)

Comment: That did not appear to work. I've tried `Criteria1:=TRUE` which did not work. I thought it could be that VBA thinks TRUE would be a variable name. So then I set a variable `Tr=TRUE` followed by `Criteria1:=Tr`, but that also did not work

Comment: If there is a formula for column `lCol` then perhaps you can make it return a `1` or `0` outcome (e.g. `=IF(foo,1,0)`) as a workaround?

Comment: Do the values in the cells you are filtering on containing a boolean value (True/False) or do they contain a text version of True/False?  To find out, try entering a formula of `=A1*1` (if the value you want to check is in A1) - if it says `1` then the value is a boolean `TRUE` - if it says `#VALUE!` then the value is text.

Comment: @YowE3K Boolean values idd. 1*Cell returned 1. Could it have something to do with the notation of the autofilter? Many criteria need to be written between `"..."`

Comment: @RobinMackenzie, that is a nice and simple idea, thanks :)

Comment: Actually, I just tried a filter and it didn't care less whether the values were text or boolean, so it appears the filter is converting the criteria to text before filtering anyway.  Probably best to go with the suggestion from @RobinMackenzie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try use the `CBool` function to avoid using a string or language-dependent value for `TRUE` when setting the `AutoFilter`.

`CBool(1)` should be 'true' in any locale.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestLanguageIndependentBooleanForAutoFilter()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim lCol As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)

    lCol = tbl.ListColumns("xFilter").Index
    With tbl
        If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=lCol, Criteria1:=CBool(1)
    End With

End Sub
```

Works in an Australian English locale:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Criteria1:=CStr(True)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers did not work for me in Russian Excel, where I was trying to do some coding independent of language. In the end, I had to utilize a set of two cells where I manually put `TRUE` and `FALSE` values (`ИСТИНА` and `ЛОЖЬ` in Russian) and I reference their `.Text` (this is important!) instead of `.Value2` in the `Criteria`. It seems like the issue is that `Criteria` uses `.Text` from cells in the filter which may not be equal to the text `True` and `False`.

This solution is far from perfect, obviously, but, so far it's the only way I've found. It's good that Excel stores boolean values as `0` and `1`: if you open the Workbook as a zip file, you can see files like `sheet1.xml` which will have entries like this for boolean cells:

```xml
<c r="B5" s="6" t="b">
<v>0</v>
</c>
```

`t` seems to represent the type of the value—in this case `b`, which implies `boolean`.