# AutoFilter rows when multiple columns are 0 in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I'm trying to filter out values when both column B and C are equal to 0 on the same row.  When using the following code, rows are filtered out when either column, not both simultaneously, are equal to 0.

```
With Sheets("Recon").Range("$A$1:$L$2500")
    .AutoFilter Field:=Array(2, 3), Criteria1:="<>0"
End With
```

Comment: You can make a helper column and then just filter on that

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575754/filter-out-multiple-criteria-using-excel-vba