# Multiple not equal to <> in VBA Autofilter Implementation

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

So I know that I can use an array like so for autofiltering:

```
Temporary.Range("$A$1:$AB$" & RowCountTotal).AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:=Array("1","2","3"), _ Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

At the same time, I know that  I can use <> as not equals too, but I am only allowed having 2 <>'s like so:

```
Temporary.Range("$A$1:$AB$" & RowCountTotal).AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:=Array("<>1","<>2"), _ Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

When I do 3<>'s I get an error. The issue is, I need to exclude 8 items from filtering effectively using <> 8 times. My dataset is quite large so I can't filter it row by row as that will take too long.

I read other posts about this such as: [filter out multiple criteria using excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575754/filter-out-multiple-criteria-using-excel-vba)

but they all used for loops and what not, which I can't have for this. After filtering I will need to copy the filtered worksheet into a new one. How should I approach this?

Comment: You cannot avoid a loop but you could write the data into an array and then loop through the array which would be much faster than looping through cells. if you could share the 8 criteria (conditions), I would post an example.

Comment: Just imagine the conditions are A, B, C, D etc...I want to get the logic and idea down first. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Advanced Filter if you have a range you can use to place the criteria (you can use a hidden sheet, or a range on the same sheet as the table you're filtering).

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim wsTemporary As Worksheet, hdr, RowCountTotal As Long, filterColNum As Long
    Dim rngTable As Range, rngFilter As Range, arrExclude, i As Long, arrFilter
    
    Set wsTemporary = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("temp")  'where your data is
    
    RowCountTotal = wsTemporary.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set rngTable = wsTemporary.Range("$A$1:$AB$" & RowCountTotal) 'range to filter
    filterColNum = 24                                             'filter on this column index
    hdr = rngTable.Cells(1, filterColNum).Value                   'header to filter on
    
    arrExclude = Array(2, 4, 5, 6, 10)          'for example
    ReDim arrFilter(1 To 2, 1 To UBound(arrExclude) + 1)  'for the criteria values
    'build an array for the filter range content
    For i = LBound(arrExclude) To UBound(arrExclude)
        arrFilter(1, i + 1) = hdr
        arrFilter(2, i + 1) = "<>" & arrExclude(i)
    Next i
    'put the criteria table below the data table
    Set rngFilter = wsTemporary.Cells(RowCountTotal + 10, 1) _
                               .Resize(UBound(arrFilter, 1), UBound(arrFilter, 2))
    rngFilter.Value = arrFilter
    
    'filter the table
    rngTable.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
                            CriteriaRange:=rngFilter, _
                            Unique:=False
    
    rngFilter.Clear 'clean up: remove the criteria table
        
End Sub
```

Comment: what do the range("a1") and range("a2")s mean? I am confused to why those cells but not D1 or whatnot as we are filtering for column = 4 in your example

Comment: Advanced Filter requires a "criteria range" where the header(s) correspond to the headers in the range to be filtered, and the rows below contain values to use for filtering.  The code above creates a criteria range on a separate sheet (codename `filter`).  Did you try it out?  https://trumpexcel.com/excel-advanced-filter/   https://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter02.html

Comment: Not yet, was confused on how to implement it. So if I were to implement the code I would change the filtercolumn to 24, array values and sheet1 to an existing sheet? Should I just keep the Filter part the same? Sorry I am still relatively new to vba!

Comment: I've updated my example to make it closer to your original post.

Comment: Helpful & instructive +:); fyi you might be interested in my alternative via newer dynamic array reorganization using `Application.Index()` @TimWilliams

Answer (score 2):

### Write Non-Existing

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub writeNonExisting()
    
    Const rCount As Long = 10
    Const CriteriaList As String = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H"
    
    Dim Criteria() As String: Criteria = Split(CriteriaList, ",")
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Temporary.Range("A1:AB" & rCount)
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(Data, 2)
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    For i = 1 To rCount
        If IsError(Application.Match(Data(i, 24), Criteria, 0)) Then
            k = k + 1
            For j = 1 To cCount
                Data(k, j) = Data(i, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    
    With Temporary.Parent.Worksheets.Add
        .Range("A1").Resize(k, cCount).Value = Data
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative Udf `RemoveExceptions()`**

Using the new dynamic array features of MS 365/Excel 2019+ you could code the following user defined function as base for any dynamic formula input:

```
Function RemoveExceptions(DataRng As Range, exceptions, Optional LookUpCol As Long = 1)
'Note: Execptions can be as well a range as an array
    With Application
        Dim data: data = DataRng.Value
        Dim crit: crit = DataRng.Columns(LookUpCol)  ' data column to be matched
    '[1]Check positions
        Dim chk: chk = .Transpose(.Match(crit, exceptions, 0))
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(chk) To UBound(chk)
            chk(i) = IIf(IsNumeric(chk(i)), "DELETE", i)
        Next
        chk = Filter(chk, "DELETE", False)      ' validrow positions
    '[2]Remove exceptions from data
        RemoveExceptions = .Transpose(.Index(data, chk, Evaluate("row(1:" & DataRng.Columns.Count & ")")))
    End With
End Function
```

**Possible formula input**

You could display the data to be filtered based on exclusion criteria by entering the following formula e.g. in cell `A2` of a results sheet

- either via criteria *array* as 2nd argument *(data range as 1st arg, lookup column = `24` as 3rd parameter)*

```
 =RemoveExceptions(temp!A2:AB100;{2;4;6;8};24)
```

- or via an extra criteria *range* as 2nd argument

```
 =RemoveExceptions(temp!A2:AB100;temp!AD2:AD6;24)
```

Comment: I don't have the dynamic arrays yet, but works fine using Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: Thank you for responding as it helps me to see that it can be handled even before.

Comment: When entered using C+S+E as a regular array formula, the empty lines are all #N/A (since you have to fill the array formula in a range the same size as the input table, as you don't know how many lines - if any - will be excluded)