# Excel VBA AutoFilter Codes

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I want to filter a list of industries by using their industry code (e.g. C10.3, H53.1 etc.)as criteria. At the end, I want my sheet just showing those industries.

The data I want to filter is in Tabelle1 Column 21. Furthermore, I have stated my industry codes on Tabelle3 Column B. However, the following code does not execute.

Does anyone know why and how I can adjust it to my needs?

```
Sub Autofilter()    
    Dim Bereich As Range
    Dim IndustryCode As Variant

    Set Bereich = Tabelle1.UsedRange
    IndustryCode = Tabelle3.Range("B:B").Value2

    Bereich.Autofilter Field:=21, Criteria1:="=" & IndustryCode  
End Sub
```

Comment: what is `NACECode` ? And "*does not execute*" does not describe what happens.

Comment: did you try to use `, Operator:=xlFilterValues`?  Like `Bereich.Autofilter Field:=21, Criteria1:="=" & IndustryCode, Operator:=xlFilterValues`

Comment: @PEH: "does not execute" means, when I try to run the macro it does not work and shows "Run-Time error '13': Typen unverträglich

Comment: Error message without telling in which line it occurs is usless in most cases. So in which line do you get the error?

Comment: You need to use loop to select each value in range B:B. Autofilter cant select all the values at a time

Comment: @PEH: Sorry my fault. It occours in Bereich.Autofilter Field:=21, Criteria1:="=" & IndustryCode

Comment: @Deepak: Thanks for your advice. How would you code that in my case? :)

Comment: @Deepak No loop needed, you just need to transform the matrix ;) making a 1 dimenional array out of a 2 dimensional one and use this as criteria (see my answer).

Comment: Note, that this solution can only work for non-numeric filter values because `Variant` is most likely to assume `String` values. So, if you are storing numbers as string into an array and then filter by that array then the filter will be a string filter (on a possibly numeric column).

Comment: @Ralph The `Variant` is only that the variable can contain an array but inside that array the items of that array still can be of type `Double` (when your read numbers from a range then `vartype(IndustryCode(1))` is Double if the first entry is a number even if `IndustryCode` is Variant). And that fact finally causes the issue that it fails filtering on true numbers. If they were strings then filtering would work. Excel is kinda odd with filtering and true numbers in VBA but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42932732/3219613) illustrates it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transpose the `IndustryCode` because this

```
IndustryCode = Tabelle3.Range("B:B").Value2
```

results in a 2 dimensional `array(1 to 1048576, 1 to 1)` but the criteria awaits a 1 dimensional array.

So after

```
IndustryCode = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(IndustryCode)
```

you get a 1 dimensional `array(1 to 65536)` which you can use as `Criteria1` together with `Operator:=xlFilterValues`.

```
Sub aaa()
    Dim Bereich As Range
    Dim IndustryCode As Variant

    Set Bereich = Tabelle1.UsedRange
    IndustryCode = Tabelle3.Range("B:B").Value2
    IndustryCode = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(IndustryCode)

    Bereich.AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=IndustryCode, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Note that it is not very elegant to use the whole column because the array has `65536` entries which means most are empty. A better way would be using only the range as array that is filled with data:

```
IndustryCode = Tabelle3.Range("B1", Tabelle3.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2
```

This will reduce the array to the used part of column B only.

---

Also note that if `IndustryCode` (column B) contains true numbers they need to be converted into strings with a loop over the array.

```
ary(i) = CStr(ary(i))
```

as illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42932732/3219613).