# AutoFilter connect with and/or

Tags: vba, excel, logic, logical-operators, autofilter

I have a huge data sheet which I want to "AutoFilter" by three different criteria which are in three different columns.

Is it possible in Excel VBA to connect three AutoFilters with a logic like:

Criteria 1 **AND** (Criteria2 **AND/OR** Criteria3)

For example, I am analiyzing football teams by league, market value, revenue.
Therefore, I want to filter my data by following criterias:

Criteria 1: They have to play in the highest league in their country
**AND**
(Criteria 2: Market Value most be >= 300 Mio 
**AND/OR**
Criteria 3: Revenue most be >= 100 Mio )

Thank you :)

Comment: Simply reverse [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497659/excel-vba-autofilter-all-but-three/35120033?s=1|66.1409#35120033)

Comment: @Jeeped: What exactly do you mean by "simply reverse"?

Comment: Given the prompt reply I gather that you didn't bother reading the post behind the link or if you did, you didn't absorb it.

Comment: @Jeeped: Sorry my fault. I didn't see the link. I will check it out, thanks :)

Comment: @Jeeped: Okay I have checked it but I still don't see what you mean by "simply reverse" it? This Problem is for only one column, mine is for three different. Can you please explain it to me? :)

Answer (score 0):

**Sort-of**.
Filtering by `AND` across columns is easy, but filtering by `OR` is *only* possible within a single column...  *unless* you add a "calculation" column and filter on that instead.

To expand:  Create a new column, something like "High Revenue or Market Value", and give it a formula which is `TRUE` when [Market Value]>= 300 millon `OR` [Revenue] >= 100 millon or `FALSE` otherwise, then filter on that column for `TRUE`. (i.e. if "Market Value" is column B, and "Revenues" is column C, then the formula for row 2 would be `=OR(B2>=300000000,C2>=100000000)`