# comparison not equals in Array by Filter

Tags: excel, vba

criteria 1:= Array("<>David","<>Steven") .... Isn't working in vb Macro excel

Please help me, why not working when I give comparison not equals in Array by Filter.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify up to two 'does-not-equal' criteria in an AutoFilter.

```
with myFilterRange
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>David", _
                Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>Steven"
end with
```

For additional 'does-not-equal' criteria, see [Excel VBA autofilter all but three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497659/excel-vba-autofilter-all-but-three/35120033?s=6|0.0000#35120033).

Comment: Thanks sir.  But I will create filter multiple in Array...like this: Array(get data from sheet).. and in data Array I want give not equals comparison.