# Macro to remove all orders with 'XXX' status, then remove all order types besides: Z , L, ZR

Tags: excel, vba

We have a monthly process of manually exporting information from SAP to Excel and then creating a production schedule from it. One of the first steps when getting the information to excel is filtering down to certain criteria and removing the rest. I am a begginer with VBA/Macros, and I can only find examples online on how to delete rows via certain criteria instead of deleting rows outside of my desired criteria..

I want to remove all orders with 'XXX' status.
Then I want to remove all order types EXCEPT: Z, L, ZR

I am assuming this is possible, and that I just am not educated enough on vba to figure it out quite yet.. Let me know, thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497659/excel-vba-autofilter-all-but-three

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the filter for the ones you want to keep and copy them to a new workbook or a temporary sheet that you can copy back from.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

    Const COL_STATUS = 1 ' column no
    Const COL_ORDERTYPE = 4 ' column no
       
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
       
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set wsTemp = .Sheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    End With
       
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws.UsedRange
        .AutoFilter COL_STATUS, Array("Z", "L", "ZR"), xlFilterValues
        .AutoFilter COL_ORDERTYPE, "<>ZZZ"
        .Copy wsTemp.Range("A1")
        .AutoFilter
        .Cells.Clear
    End With
       
    With wsTemp
        .UsedRange.Copy ws.Range("A1")
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done"
  
End Sub
```